# Try to remove unused string but it's not working

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin

I'm trying to remove the unused string from string.xml but it's showing noting in the preview I have many strings which are unused

I follow these steps:

- open string.xml
- right-click
- select refactor -> unused resource

Comment: Can you please explain what exactly you want to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried to run with

`Code->Analyze code->Run Inspection By Name` (or shortcut: `Ctrl` + `Alt` + `Shift` + `i` for windows and `Cmd` + `Alt` + `Shift` + `i` for mac)

There you can look for `unused resources`

You can do this for your whole project or just for your `strigs.xml` file